# Google Analytics GTM android get client id

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

im trying get **client id** using google tag manager in Android project and print it.
How its possible? I'm search all unternet and dont find answer.
It can be varry easy. In JavaScript it doing

```
ga.getAll()[0].get("clientId")
```

But How its get in Java Android project?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Obtain a tracker object from your GA (or GTM) SDK

tracker.get("&cid");
doc: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html#get(java.lang.String)

provided you obtained your tracker like below:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-000-1"); // Send hits to tracker id UA-000-1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
clientId = tracker.get("&cid")
```

Comment: The question is about Android, your answer is not (looks like Javascript to me but I'm not going to make any  assumption here)